# How to compile a file with tilde (`~`) in the name?

Tags: pdftex, xetex, compiling, tilde

I have just discovered with surprise that if a TeX file has a tilde `~` in its name, `xelatex` and `pdflatex` refuse to compile it:

```
$ cat te\~st.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdflatex te\~st.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `te'.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
<*> te~
       st.tex
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

Meanwhile, this file compiles ok, even though the tilde is not escaped in any way:

```latex
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{hell~o.tex}
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug? Is there an *easy* way to compile files with tilde in the name?

I wanted to use tilde for readability, like in `arithmetic-1~natural-numbers.tex`.

I am using TeXLive 2021 on Linux Mint 21.1.

Comment: `pdflatex te\string~st` should work. But I would avoid such names. Why don't you use hyphens or underscore?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, `pdflatex te\string~st.tex` does not work either on my system. I will find it very inconvenient if `pdflatex` has its own rules for escaping special characters in file names, and in particular shell auto-completion cannot be used. I would prefer a tilde in my case because I already use hyphens in each part that I wanted to separate with tilde. I thought that tilde was a fairly common file name character.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, this has worked indeed: `pdflatex te\\string~st`.

Comment: @Alexey This is a shell issue. You can either escape the backslash with ``\\`` or use `pdflatex 'te\string~st'` to avoid shell expansion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling

```bash
pdflatex name
```

is the same as calling `pdflatex` and specifying `name` at the `**` prompt.

The file name is passed unchanged to the TeX interpreter (`~` will not undergo shell expansion to the home directory name) and the usual rules of TeX will apply. Specifying tokens at the `**` prompt is (almost) the same as doing

```
\input name
```

(the primitive `\input`) and TeX follows its rules, namely to do full token expansion until finding something that's not a character. In your case, `~` expands to

```
\nobreakspace{}
```

and then

```
\protect\nobreakspace•{}
```

(where `•` stands for a trailing space in the name). Since at this time `\protect` is `\relax`, the file name is determined to be `te`.

You need to protect the `~` from expansion at the TeX level, which can be done in several ways:

```bash
pdflatex te\\string~st
pdflatex 'te\string~st'
pdflatex '\input{\detokenize{te~st}}'
pdflatex '\input{\unexpanded{te~st}}'
```

You might want to write a shell script for running `pdflatex` (or other engine) with “strange” file names.